# Is "Zu dieser Zeit..." equivalent to "At this time..."?

Tags: preposition, phrase

Alles Wichtiges steht in der Frage da oben, aber ich kann es auch ein bisschen erläutern.

In English when I'm describing a period of time in the past I usually say either,

"At this time...", "During this time...", or "In this time..."

When I think about finding equivalents for these phrases in German "Während dieser Zeit..." and "In dieser Zeit..." seem to cover the last two respectively.

As far as the first phrase goes, I have often noticed "Zu dieser Zeit..." being used in a manner that seems to give a rough equivalent. Is this correct to assume? Are there any nuances of meaning that "Zu dieser Zeit..." has which aren't covered by "At this time..."?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct: "Zu dieser Zeit…” is a good translation of “At this time…” and covers most nuances of meaning.
Another possibility would be "Zu jener Zeit" (at **that** time)

Comment: Short "Zur Zeit" is also possible. Dont confuse it with "zurzeit" though ;)

Comment: @Ales The question was about describing periods of time *in the past*